# How do I copy Array values to a structure

Tags: vb.net

I would like to to copy that values of an array into a Structure.

Example:

```
' The Array
Dim Columns(2) As String

' The Structure
Private Structure Fields
    Public FName As String
    Public LName As String
    Public Email As String
End Structure

' I would like to map it like so:
Fields.FName = Columns(0)
Fields.LName = Columns(1)
Fields.Email = Columns(2)
```

Obviously I could write a function if it was so simple, but really there are over 25 columns and it's a pain to write a function that would map it.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have a structure with over 25 columns in the first place?  Good practice dictates that any type of that size be a class rather than a structure.

Comment: I would do it like that, it's only 25 columns. Making sure to use constant instead of just numbers for each column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no simple way that will work in all cases.  What you are complaining is too much effort is the only way to guarantee that it will work in all cases.

That said, if you can guarantee that the number of elements in the array matches the number of properties/fields in the structure/class and that they are in the same order and of the same types then you could use Reflection in a loop, e.g.

```
Private Function Map(source As Object()) As SomeType
    Dim result As New SomeType
    Dim resultType = result.GetType()
    Dim fields = resultType.GetFields()

    For i = 0 To source.GetUpperBound(0)
        fields(i).SetValue(result, source(i))
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

EDIT:

The code I have provided works as is if SomeType is a class but, as I missed the first time around, not for a structure.  The reason is that structures are value types and therefore a copy of the original object is being sent to `SetValue`, so the field value never gets set on that original object.  In theory, to prevent a copy being created, you should be able to simply box the value, i.e. wrap it in an `Object` reference:

```
Private Function Map(source As Object()) As SomeType
    Dim result As Object = New SomeType
    Dim resultType = result.GetType()
    Dim fields = resultType.GetFields()

    For i = 0 To source.GetUpperBound(0)
        fields(i).SetValue(result, source(i))
    Next

    Return DirectCast(result, SomeType)
End Function
```

As it turns out though, the VB compiler treats that a little differently than the C# compiler treats the equivalent C# code and it still doesn't work.  That's because, in VB, the boxed value gets unboxed before being passed to the method, so a copy is still created.  In order to make it work in VB, you need to use a `ValueType` reference instead of `Object`:

```
Private Function Map(source As Object()) As SomeType
    Dim result As ValueType = New SomeType
    Dim resultType = result.GetType()
    Dim fields = resultType.GetFields()

    For i = 0 To source.GetUpperBound(0)
        fields(i).SetValue(result, source(i))
    Next

    Return DirectCast(result, SomeType)
End Function
```

Comment: Not working. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/NXMYw2XH. The `result` ends up blank. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As it turns out, the code I provided will work for a class but not for a structure.  I've provided an edit that explains why and how to get around it.  I'd still use a class rather than structure and properties instead of fields though, unless you have a specific requirement to use a structure, e.g. it's for PInvoke.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN If you do this approach, you better put good comments. A new developer might add a property (right in the middle) and wonder why the code isn't working anymore.

Comment: @the_lotus: yes, I sure will put in good comments! I learned my lesson about this some time ago. Also, I probobly will be using a class instead of a structure. Even just to add some built in functions. Additionally, I want to make sure that it is fine if the class has more fields/properties than the array.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN, if the array had more elements then the object had fields or properties then you would have to use the array for the upper bound of the `For` loop.  You would also have to ensure that the fields or properties that you wanted to set came before those that you didn't and that they were in the same order as the corresponding elements of the array.  To be honest, I don't know what controls the order of `FieldInfo` or `PropertyInfo` objects returned by `GetFields` or `GetProperties`.  It may well be the order that they physically appear in the source code but I don't know that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: so its ok if the class has extra fields, properties etc AFTER these?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Can you also post the equivalent C# code just for reference?